# Filter Search source/results by list's choice column

Tags: search, filter, content-search-web-part

Hello Sharepointers,

I've created a Discussion List, with a choice column where users must specify either Internal or External (our discussions will either cover internal or external issues).

When my users search, they will specify whether they're looking through internal or external discussions.  This will cut down loads of unhelpful results.

I know I can create a Search Vertical to specify things like content types or source locations.

I know I can create a filter for a list view.

But how do I/should I create a search vertical option for them to search through internal or external discussions?  Or should I be taking another approach?  Should I create a page with a custom search box, with a Refinement webpart below it?

Many thanks!
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You have MANY options. FOr example, you could create a search vertical just for Discussions. Then use the Internal/External choice as a refiner. (Create a refinable Managed Property based on the Crawled Property and mark it Refinable.) Then users could search for an issue then select Internal or External. The same way you would search for a TV and then choose Sony over Samsung.

Alternatively, you could create a vertical for Internal and another for External. Then users queries would be immediately filtered. It all depends on what you want them to do.

Comment: I can't find how to restrict a vertical's query specifically to our Discussions list, or to filter according to one column.  I've tried adding this based on these instructions ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794227.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ): 

{searchTerms?}(contentclass:sts_listitem) path:https://ourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/it/projects/ AND InternalExternal:Internal

But this yields no results.  

How do I create a vertical restricted to one list, AND only items with Internal selected?

I'm reading Technets but can't find this information.

Thanks again!

Comment: As you start creating your query begin in the search center. Try `contentClass=STS_ListItem_DiscussionBoard` then add the path including the protocol. Finally, make sure the Managed Property `InternalExternal` is configured correctly. You can use the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool to test your work.